# Get Only unique values from an array

Tags: groovy

I have an array of arrays and I need to get only unique values `empname` and `dept` from that array without depending on `hoursWorked`.

```
def data = [[empname:'Test1',dept:10,hoursWorked:6],            
        [empname:'Test1',dept:10,hoursWorked:2],
        [empname:'Test2',dept:10,hoursWorked:10]] as Set

println data;
```

I used Set so that it contains only unique values. Since `hoursWorked` is different I am getting all the three values.

I want the expected result to be:

```
[[empname:Test1, dept:10],[empname:Test2, dept:10]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast a list of maps to a set of maps, but first, you need to transform the list to contain only the map entries you are interested in. Consider the following example:

```
data.collect { [empname: it.empname, dept: it.dept] }.toSet()
```

In the first run, it transforms each map to a map that contains only the two keys, and after that, it transforms a list to a set, so it contains only unique pairs of `empname` and `dept`.

It produces expected output:

```
[[empname:Test1, dept:10], [empname:Test2, dept:10]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, that won't work as the values are different.

You can write a comparison closure for your data and pass it to `unique`

Take care though, as `unique` mutates the original list

```
def data = [
    [empname:'Test1',dept:10,hoursWorked:6],            
    [empname:'Test1',dept:10,hoursWorked:2],
    [empname:'Test2',dept:10,hoursWorked:10]
]

println data.unique { a, b -> a.empname <=> b.empname ?: a.dept <=> b.dept }
// Prints: [[empname:Test1, dept:10, hoursWorked:6], [empname:Test2, dept:10, hoursWorked:10]]

println data
// Prints: [[empname:Test1, dept:10, hoursWorked:6], [empname:Test2, dept:10, hoursWorked:10]]
// Original collection was mutated
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [unique](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#unique(groovy.lang.Closure)) with a closure returning values that are only based on the keys you want to use:

```
data.unique{[it['empname'], it['dept']]}
===> [[empname:Test1, dept:10, hoursWorked:6], 
      [empname:Test2, dept:10, hoursWorked:10]]
```

`data.unique{[it['empname'], it['dept']]}` will let Groovy compute a collection of distinct values based on the `empname` and `dept` keys only. It's up to you to discard the `hoursWorked` keys.